# Post request but getting error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST Laravel/Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, http, laravel-5, post

I am sending a POST request from javascript to laravel backend like so:

```
post(url, 'data=' + JSON.stringify({'app_name': appName, 'business_name': partnerName, 
'source': source, 'http_referrer': referrer, 'link' : link}));

function post(url, data) {
  let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('POST', url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  http.send(data);
}
```

But getting an error: `The GET method is not supported for this route.`
The error appears when i'm passing long url params like:

http://127.0.0.1:7000/affiliates/businessName/Tobi?source=Koala?utm_source=koala-apps-shopify-inspector&utm_medium=koala-apps-shopify-inspector&utm_campaign=koala-apps-shopify-inspector&utm_term=koala-apps-shopify-inspector&utm_content=koala-apps-shopify-inspector

Until this point of url http://127.0.0.1:7000/affiliates/businessName/Tobi?source=Koala?utm_source=koala-apps-shopify-inspector the POST request sends fine, when there is more multiple params getting the following error.

The route for recieving the request is:

```
Route::post('create-affiliate-opens', 'AffiliatesController@createAffiliateOpens');
```

Controller method:

```
 public function createAffiliateOpens(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->data, true);
    $user = User::where('business_name', '=', $data['business_name'])- 
>first();
    if (!$user) return abort(404);

    $user->affiliateOpens()->create([
        'ip'            => $request->ip(),
        'http_referrer' => $data['http_referrer'],
        'link'          => $data['link'],
        'app_name'      => $data['app_name'],
        'business_name' => $data['business_name'],
        'source'        => preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", 
 $data['source']),
        'created_at'    => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i'),
    ]);

    return $this->respondCreated([
        'success' => true,
    ]);
}
```

How could I fix this problem, what am I not seeing?

If something is not clear, please say so, I will provide more information.

Comment: I include a csrf token in all pages in head section like so:
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: But why you say so if  when sending shorter params I don't get this error?